# How to export menu per role permission in features module?

Tags: users, features

I added `custom permission` in my menu using [menu_per_role](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module. I want to export the permission configuration that I made in my menu. using [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module my question is how can I export my menu permission configuration. is `features` module support exporting configuration came from `menu_per_role module`? I also tried to check it in [strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this module [roles_for_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/roles_for_menu) this module exactly what I need, it allows me to export the configuration in features.

Features module support it.